# combine objects in an array and push to an array in the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

- In the end there should be only one object per `name`.
- If there are
  multiple objects with the same name make it so that the `number` array for each object get combined into the one object for that name
- The one object with the same name should not have duplicate elements in the `number` array.
- The elements in the number array should appear in the same order as they appear in the original array.

  ```
  var arrT = [
      {name : "x.com", number :["123-456-789"]}, {name : "x.com", number :["452-123-789"]},{name : "y.com", number :["123-456-000"]}, 
      {name : "x.com", number :["123-456-789"]}, {name : "y.com", number :["123-456-000"]}, {name : "b.com", number :["178-456-000"]}


      ]

  output should be:[
  {name : "x.com", number : ["123-456-789", "452-123-789"]}, //notice: 123-456-789 didn't appear twice
  {name : "y.com", number : ["123-456-000"]},
  {name : "b.com", number :["178-456-000"]}

  ]
  ```

I was able to find out how many times an object with the same name occurred

```
var occurrences = nArr.reduce(function(acc, curr,i){
    if(typeof acc[curr.name] == "undefined"){
        acc[curr.name] = 1;
    }else{
        acc[curr.name] += 1
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(occurrences)

var moreThanOne = [];
for(var key in occurrences){
    if(occurrences[key] > 1){
        moreThanOne.push(key);
    }
}
console.log("moreThanOne", moreThanOne)
```

but then it got complicated because I didn't know how to remove the duplicates and leave one and combine the `number` array

Comment: Oh. I was thinking just now I could do this with just reduce. and forget about the counting part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have some constraints but that's how I'd do it.

Loop over all of your object and put them into an object. The key of the object will be the name. Check if the object exists, if it doesn't add it and replace the `number` by `[number]`, if the object already exists, simply add the number with `push`.

Once you looped over all your objects, convert that object to a list and that's it.

```
function groupByName(accum, obj) {
  if (accum[obj.name]) {
    // add all numbers! don't check for uniqueness yet
    accum[obj.name].number = accum[obj.name].concat(obj.number)
  } else {
    accum[obj.name] = obj
    obj.number = [obj.number]
  }
  return accum
}

function removeDuplicates(accum, value) {
  if (accum.length == 0 && accum[accum.length - 1] != value) {
    accum.push(value)
  }
  return accum
}

function toList(context) {
  return function (key) {
    var obj = context[key]
    obj.number.sort()
    obj.number = obj.number.reduce(removeDuplicates, [])
    return obj
  }
}

objs = arrT.reduce(groupByName, {})
output = Object.keys(objs).map(toList(objs))
```

Note that I'm ediding the first object so if there is no use for those objects anywhere else, that's fine... if not, you should copy in the reduce function instead of modifying and existing object.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: Ah I didn't see `number` is already an array... then you have to loop over all numbers and check if they're already there..

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to keep the unique numbers you just have to check if the numbers are already in.

This example creates a new object first, checks if the the name exists already, when it doesn't exist, it adds it as a completely new reference (including the number array, so your original source remains the same) and if it does exist, it will loop through the number array to see which ones should be added still.

```js
var arrT = [{
  name: "x.com",
  number: ["123-456-789"]
}, {
  name: "x.com",
  number: ["452-123-789"]
}, {
  name: "y.com",
  number: ["123-456-000"]
}, {
  name: "x.com",
  number: ["123-456-789"]
}, {
  name: "y.com",
  number: ["123-456-000"]
}, {
  name: "b.com",
  number: ["178-456-000"]
}];

var reduced = arrT.reduce((nextState, item) => {
  var key = item.name,
    o;
  if (!(o = nextState[key])) {
    // clones the item, and the number array
    nextState[key] = { ...item, number: [...item.number] };
  } else {
    item.number.forEach(number => o.number.indexOf(number) === -1 && o.number.push(number));
  }
  return nextState;
}, {});

console.log(arrT);
console.log(Object.keys(reduced).map(key => reduced[key]));
```

Comment: Looping over and over the numbers as the number list grow will take more time. It's not a huge deal because it's unlikely that a person will have 1000 of numbers but you'd be better up filtering the numbers 1 time once you accumulated all numbers.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Yeah, that's true, however for the current data set, this is not something "big", though I can see your point

Answer (score 0):

Another (ES6) version for the mix: with a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
let  arrT = [{name : "x.com", number :["123-456-789"]}, {name : "x.com", number :["452-123-789"]},{name : "y.com", number :["123-456-000"]}, {name : "x.com", number :["123-456-789"]}, {name : "y.com", number :["123-456-000"]}, {name : "b.com", number :["178-456-000"]}    ];
    
 let  res = [...arrT.reduce((m,o) => {
    let set = m.get(o.name);
    if(!set) m.set(o.name, set = new Set());
    for(let n of o.number) set.add(n);
    return m;
 }, new Map())]
 .map(([na,[...nrs]])=>({name:na,number:nrs}));
 
 console.log(res);
```